# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, servlets, apache-poi, xlsx, xssf

when i tried to create a workbook in normal java class it is creating but when i tried to run the same on servlet it is throwing exceptions

Normal java class

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class Sampleclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FileInputStream file;
        try {
            file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Rajasekhar\\Desktop\\EmployeeDetails.xlsx"));
            Workbook book=new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            System.out.println(book);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Servlet

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class sampleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
             {
        FileInputStream file;
        try {
            file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Rajasekhar\\Desktop\\EmployeeDetails.xlsx"));
            Workbook book=new XSSFWorkbook(file);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("exception occured is "+e);      
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("exception occured is "+e);      
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

the exception occured was

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [upload] in context with path [/Temp2] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    at sampleServlet.doGet(sampleServlet.java:23)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have added all required apache poi jars.

Comment: make sure that you have the apache-poi jar in the web-inf lib folder

Comment: Please comment as how you resolved the problem.

Answer (score 13):

Download `poi-ooxml.jar` and add it to your classspath.

Comment: is it in your tomcat classpath? in WEB-INF/lib of your application or in the lib folder of your tomcat?

Comment: i have added in application   (build path config _ add external jars)

Comment: How you resolved the issue, I am struggling with the same problem.

Comment: I'm using Grails 3 and adding this dependency solves this for me.

Answer (score 13):

You need the file `poi-ooxml.jar` in your classpath as [@Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3636601/jens) said.

You are using the correct `import` statement but it seems that you don't have the file `poi-ooxml.jar` in the class path of your web container.

If you are using **maven**, you should put this dependency in your `pom.xml` inside the `<dependencies>` tag:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: the issue is different. as you can see he have the correct imports: 
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
you should stop answering only to get points. -1

Comment: Thank you for your feed back [@PedroSequeira](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5698678/pedro-sequeira), I will try improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

i know this may be late but the problem was that you may ignore the file `xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar` which is in separate file from other apache jar (ooxml-lib)

Answer (score 0):

Adding/Updating below Gradle dependency for Apache Poi should resolve the issue .

```
compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '4.1.2'
compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.1.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you imported properly and added jar files such as poi and poi-ooxml and still facing issues then try this version

its work ...  and hope your issues will solved.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
```