# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java

Getting below error after executing my java program using Eclipse.

I tried setting classpath with `poi-ooxml-4.1.0.jar` and also with `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin` file. But still getting the same error.

Kindly let me know what file should I add to the classpath environment variable. Thanks

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook at testInterviewQuestions.test.main(test.java:17) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602) at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992908/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-poi-xssf-usermodel-xssfworkbook)

Comment: Try adding other dependencies in your class path including the poi jar. That seems missing

Comment: Tried with all the comments ..but still getting the same error ..Kindly help

Comment: Tried adding poi jar file path to the system variables and user variables but still getting the same error ..Kindly help .. thanks