# Read Write Excel File using Apache POI

Tags: java, testing, automation, apache-poi

I am getting error like [ Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap
at excelExport.ReadWriteExcel1.main(ReadWriteExcel1.java:15)) ] . Can Someone please guide me for the same.

```
package excelExport;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ReadWriteExcel1 
{
    public static void main (String []args) throws Exception
    {
        File src=new File("C:\\Users\\techbrain\\Downloads\\Selenium Jar\\TestData.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
        XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet=wb.getSheetAt(0);
          
        int rowcount=sheet.getLastRowNum()+1;
        System.out.println("Total rows is "+rowcount);
        for(int i=0; i<rowcount; i++)
        {
            String data0=sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
            System.out.println("Data from Row"+i+" is "+data0);
        }
         wb.close();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have edited your question. Selenium cannot work with excel files. Selenium work with browsers. What you are writing about is Apache POI library.

Comment: Aren't you just missing the `commons-collections4` library ?

Comment: I believe Collections4 dependency resolve it.. You need to use jar for it.. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.1

Comment: @AnilK
I also use the Commons-Collection jar file.

https://prnt.sc/v2ri09

Comment: Now error/exception changed, you need to add another dependency jar.. follow this link..  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26993119/8607192 . Best to use maven/gradle.